# Mini Map Camera show a black image instead of rendering camera view

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I want to create a minimap. I followed the steps that are in unity documentation (create a new  simple camera, RowImage , RenderTexture and put the RenderTexture in the camera and RowImage) but when I run the application it show a black image instead the minicamera view. I also have an ArCamera (vuforia) on the scene can this be the problem?

Here are the screenshots..

[image: Sceen View]
[image: Sample View 2]
[image]

[image: This is the ArCamera and her settings]

Comment: It would probably help to add some screenshots of the issue and your camera settings for all cameras

Comment: Try to set the `Depth` of the minimapCamera to e.g. `2`

Comment: Click on RawImage from the hierarchy and upload its details shown in inspector. Just make sure you are assigning created MinMapRenderTexture to texture field of RawImage

Comment: @derHugo I tried this but did not work.

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti still the same result.

Comment: Disable ARcore camera and check if it works

Comment: @PraveenPanishetti if I disable the ARCamera it work, but I need the ARCamera...